# Flutter how to play youtube playlist videos?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to play youtube playlist videos in flutter using youtube API Key and playlist Id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embed YouTube Videos in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022563/embed-youtube-videos-in-flutter)

Comment: you can start from [here](https://youtu.be/7IG5kRFIMZw)

Comment: Use can use that package: https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_api

Answer (score 0):

This is a long process but [this blog](https://medium.com/vipin-vijayan/how-to-use-youtube-apis-and-play-youtube-videos-in-flutter-c47bec8cb643) will teach you the basics.

> 1. Access YouTube apis in Flutter
> 2. Get YouTube channel Info
> 3. Get YouTube Videos list
> 4. Play YouTube videos.

These plugins are also needed:

- [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http)
- [youtube_player_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)
- [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Prior to that, these needs to be ready:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started
- https://console.developers.google.com/
- https://app.quicktype.io/

You can watch [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UkEA5cSYgdE) for a more detailed process of set-up and implementations.